# How and why can Physics2D.Raycast method be used in an if statment, as it does not return a boolean value?

Tags: unity

Pretty much as the title asks, why is this code possible?

```
if (Physics2D.Raycast(...)) {

}
```

even though the method itself returns `RaycastHit2D`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The answer to questions about the Unity API can generally be found in the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D-collider.html):

> RaycastHit2D implements an implicit conversion operator converting to bool which checks [the collider] property allowing it to be used as a simple condition check for whether a hit occurred or not.

What this means is that the `RaycastHit2D` structure's code looks something like this under the hood:

```
public struct RayCastHit2D {
    public Collider2D collider;

    public static implicit operator bool(RaycastHit2D hit) {
        return hit.collider != null;
    }
}
```

This says to the compiler "wherever you see a `RaycastHit2D` used like a boolean, you can automatically convert it by running this method (which returns `true` if there was a collider hit, and `false` otherwise), without requiring the user to type out the cast or comparison explicitly.

Comment: Thank you sir. This now makes perfect sense!

Comment: Heh looks like I missed that part!